# Нужно исправить ошибку с list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно создать функцию-генератор, которая при ее применении к итерируемому объекту сможет
задерживать значение итерируемого объекта на текущей итерации, а также номер этой итерации.
Последовательность вывода неважна (может быть: номер итерации, значение; или же значение,
номер итерации)

Написанный код:

```
def func_gen(obj):
    counter = 0
    if counter < len(obj):
        counter += 1 
        for i in obj:
            yield obj[i], counter
    else:
        raise StopIteration 


obj1 = [1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5 , 8] #первый объект, кот-ый пришел на ум и итер-ся, список 
a = func_gen(obj1)
for j in a:
    print (j)
```

Описание проблемы: не выводит первый элемент списка и номер итерации всегда равен одному, + выводит ошибки

Вывод:

```
(2, 1)                                                                                                                          
(3, 1)                                                                                                                          
(4, 1)                                                                                                                          
(5, 1)                                                                                                                          
(8, 1)                                                                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                              
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                          
    for j in a:                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 6, in func_gen                                                                                           
    yield obj[i], counter                                                                                                       
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Должно быть:

```
(1, 1) 
(2, 2)                                                                                                                          
(3, 3)                                                                                                                          
(4, 4)                                                                                                                          
(5, 5)                                                                                                                          
(8, 6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что вы использовали `obj[i]`. Поскольку `i` - элементы списка, а не его индексы, `i` стало равно 8, а в списке `obj` нет элемента с номером 8. Кроме того, инкремент переменной `counter` стоит до вывода, а т.к. изначально `counter` равен нулю, первым же действием он увеличивается на 1, и элемент `obj[0]` игнорируется вовсе.

```py
def func_gen(obj):
    counter = -1
    while counter + 1 < len(obj):
        counter += 1 
        yield obj[counter], counter + 1

obj1 = [1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5 , 8] #первый объект, кот-ый пришел на ум и итер-ся, список 
a = func_gen(obj1)

for j in a:
    print (j)
```

Вывод:

```py
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)
(8, 6)
```

Но если функция должна работать ещё и со словарями, где ключи - не обязательно натуральные числа от 0 до N, лучше использовать вариант с `enumerate`. Для списков, кортежей и строк такой вариант подойдёт.

## UPD:

Решение задачи тем же способом, но рабочее и для словарей:

```py
def func_gen(obj):
    counter = -1
    if str(type(obj)) in ["<class 'str'>", "<class 'list'>", "<class 'tuple'>"]:
      while counter + 1 < len(obj):
          counter += 1
          yield obj[counter], counter + 1
    elif str(type(obj)) == "<class 'dict'>":
      for key in obj:
        counter += 1
        yield (key, obj[key]), counter

obj1 = {1:'123', 2:'321', 6:'hello'}
a = func_gen(obj1)

for j in a:
    print (j)
```

Вывод:

```py
((1, '123'), 0)
((2, '321'), 1)
((6, 'hello'), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут в `i` помещается **значение** из `obj`, а не **индекс**:

```
for i in obj:
    yield obj[i], counter
```

Чтобы работало как вы планировали, используйте `range`:

```
for i in range(len(obj)):
    yield obj[i], counter
```

Либо сразу работайте с значениями:

```
for i in obj:
    yield i, counter
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def func_gen(obj):
    for i, item in enumerate(obj):
        yield item, i+1

obj1 = [1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5 , 8] #первый объект, кот-ый пришел на ум и итер-ся, список 

a = func_gen(obj1)

for j in a:
    print (j)
```